# MySQL: get rows with consecutive dates

Tags: php, mysql

For example:

```
    id | date
   ---+------------
    1 | 2011-01-01
    2 | 2011-01-02
    3 | 2011-01-15
    4 | 2011-01-20
    5 | 2011-01-10
    6 | 2011-01-30
    7 | 2011-01-03
    8 | 2011-02-09
    9 | 2011-02-10
    10 | 2011-02-11
    11 | 2011-02-12
    12 | 2011-02-15
    13 | 2011-02-19
    14 | 2011-02-21
    15 | 2011-02-22
    16 | 2011-02-23
    17 | 2011-02-24
```

Here are some rows for example(Dates might now be always in order).
***More than one record with the same date a possible scenario***. I want to grab rows with consecutive dates. eg; for above entries I want something like:

```
   id | date
   ---+------------
    1 | 2011-01-01
    2 | 2011-01-02
    7 | 2011-01-03
    8 | 2011-02-09
    9 | 2011-02-10
    10 | 2011-02-11
    11 | 2011-02-12
    14 | 2011-02-21
    15 | 2011-02-22
    16 | 2011-02-23
    17 | 2011-02-24
```

I tried something like:

```
SELECT a.id, a.date FROM tbl a
LEFT JOIN tbl b on a.user_id = b.user_id AND a.date = b.date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

But it isn't giving me proper result and also it's much slower. So please guide me with some right process and faster.

***NOTE: its actually a attendance plan, so multiple users should have records with same date. So I need all records with consecutive dates for all users.***

Comment: is more than one record with the same date a possible scenario?

Comment: as written, you shouldn't get anything. you're joining on the same IDs, but different dates. that means you want `a.1 = b.1` **AND** different dates. sicne each of your ids is unique, there shouldn't be ANY records that match.

Comment: @lascort yes, that is also possible.

Comment: @MarcB actually it is `a.user_id = b.user_id`. What would be correct query? Help me please.

Comment: ok, that's important, include it in the question, otherwise an acceptable answer would be to just select all records between two dates being the last date the initial date plus your limit

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. totally missed the `user_id` bit...

Comment: also...when two records have the same date, which one do you want to fetch? any of them?

Comment: @lascort all of them, its actually a attendance plan, so multiple users should have records with same date. So I need all records with consecutive dates for all users.

Comment: Is this really possible without recursive queries?

Comment: @lascort honestly I don't know and not even figure out. So asked for help SO gurus',

Answer (score 1):

Start by creating an index on the date column:

```
create index idx_tbl_date on tbl(date);
```

Then, I think the following will do what you want:

```
select t.*
from tbl t
where exists (select 1 from tbl t2 where t2.date = t.date + interval 1 day) or
      exists (select 1 from tbl t2 where t2.date = t.date - interval 1 day);
```

The two exists clauses make sure that you get the first and last dates in the sequence.  With the index, this should perform well.

Comment: More than one record with the same date is also a possible scenario. what for that?

Comment: @TheSystemRestart . . . First, I don't think it makes a difference.  But more importantly, that is not the question that you asked.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think the comment was aimed at me, he just missed the textarea

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.id, a.date FROM a
LEFT JOIN b on a.id = b.id AND a.date <= b.date + INTERVAL '1 day'
ORDER BY a.date;
```

The syntax `INTERVAL 1 DAY` is wrong, I think you were looking for `INTERVAL '1 day'`. Also, if I understand your question correctly and I might not, you probably want to use <= instead of = to check if the dates are within 1 day. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Not so trivial, because it's always difficult to have the first or the last row. Here it is

```
 mysql> SET @a:=NULL;
       SELECT  DISTINCT m.id, m.date
       FROM mytable3 m,
           (SELECT IF(date<=DATE_ADD(@a, INTERVAL 1 DAY), @a, NULL) start,
                  @a:=date next  
                  FROM mytable3 ORDER BY date) m2
       WHERE m.date=m2.start 
            OR (m.date=m2.next AND m2.start IS NOT NULL);
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

```
 +----+------------+
 | id | date       |
 +----+------------+
 |  1 | 2011-01-01 |
 |  2 | 2011-01-02 |
 |  7 | 2011-01-03 |
 |  8 | 2011-02-09 |
 |  9 | 2011-02-10 |
 | 10 | 2011-02-11 |
 | 11 | 2011-02-12 |
 | 14 | 2011-02-21 |
 | 15 | 2011-02-22 |
 | 16 | 2011-02-23 |
 | 17 | 2011-02-24 |
 +----+------------+
```

11 rows in set (0.08 sec)

If you prefer not to work with variable you can also use the following:

```
       SELECT  DISTINCT m.id, m.date
       FROM mytable3 m,
           (SELECT m1.date start, m2.date next FROM mytable3 m1, mytable3 m2
            WHERE m2.date<=DATE_ADD(m1.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND m2.date>m1.date) m2
       WHERE m.date=m2.start 
            OR (m.date=m2.next AND m2.start IS NOT NULL);
```